# Dock FIll Anchor Right

Tags: c#, winforms, docking

In a `winform` program where I have a `reportviewer` control a simply want the control to adjust its height with respect to Form's height changes, without changing its witdh as well as it horizontal location. 
I define:

```
reportViewer1.Anchor = AnchorStyles.Right;
reportViewer1.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
reportViewer1.MaximumSize.Width.Equals(860);
reportViewer1.MaximumSize.Height.Equals(1600);
```

However the `reportviewer` gets to the left corner of the Form (Anchor doesn't seem to take effect)
What am I missing?

Comment: @MuhammadHisham I think you are not quite right..Dock and Anchor are suposed to work together in order to have the required result..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a control to preserve its width and to adjust its height when the Form resized, set `Anchor` to `AnchorStyles.Top | AnchorStyles.Bottom | AnchorStyles.Left` and `Dock` to `DockStyle.None`.

Comment: Great, just in my case is ...| AnchorStyles.Right... much appreiciate